# Returning a single value with Linq to SQL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm learning Linq to SQL and I'm having trouble grasping it.  I'm trying to simply return a single (boolean) value in C# with a Linq query.

I want to see if the owner of a story would like an email notification sent when new comments are added.  I would like the method that contains the Linq to SQL to return a boolean value.

```
 public bool NotifyOnComment(string username){
        var notify = (from s in db.AccountSettings
                      where s.UserName == username
                      select s.NotifyOnComment).DefaultIfEmpty(false);

        // clueless
    }
```

**Update:**

I'm doing the following now:

```
var notify = (from s in db.AccountSettings
                      where s.UserName == username
                      select s.NotifyOnComment).SingleOrDefault();

        return (bool)notify;
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Linq, by default always returns collections. If you need a single value, you can apply the [`.Single()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155325.aspx), [`.SingleOrDefault()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451.aspx) or [`.First()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976.aspx) or [`.FirstOrDefault()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx) methods.

They differ slightly in what they do. `Single()` and `SingleOrDefault()` will only work if there is *exactly* or *at most* one record in the result. `First()` and `FirstOrDefault()` will work, even if there are more results.

The `*OrDefault()` variants will return the default value for the type in case the result contained no records.

Comment: Now what if there's a chance (and there will be) that no record exists yet.  Which of those three would be best in that situation?

Comment: To be precise, a working solution might require more than just that, so look below to Justin's answer. He probably got exactly what you need.

Answer (score 9):

```
var notify = (from s in db.AccountSettings
              where s.UserName == username
              select s.NotifyOnComment).DefaultIfEmpty(false).First();

//notify will either hold a bool or the AccountSettings object so
return (!(notify == false)); // Thanks Nick. Amazing what you'll do in a hurry.
```

Comment: +1. Actually you got a working solution in contrast to me :-)

Answer (score 4):

```
var notify = (from s in db.AccountSettings
              where s.UserName == username
              select s.NotifyOnComment).Count();

return  Convert.ToBoolean(notify);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you expect just one result just use [`Single`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.single.aspx) or [`SingleOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault.aspx) to get the bool. If you want the first result you can use [`First`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.first.aspx) or [`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault.aspx).