# Querying database (SQL Server) from Microsoft Visual Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, linq

Beginner level programmer here and I've been stuck with this issue of querying my database (SQL Server) through Microsoft Visual Studio and actually returning the tuple of the result I want.

For instance.. If I want the sector of a particular Project ID, I'd query it like this in a subroutine, and call the subroutine

```
Public Sub testing()
    projectID = 1

    Dim sqlQueryObject = (From a In db.Project1 Where a.ProjectID = projectID
                          Select a.Sector)   'Using LINQ

    'Now have the object (works fine)
    'The Issue is getting the actual sector value from this query...in which I've tried a couple of things

End Sub
```

1. `dim somestring as string = Cstr(sqlQueryObject)`
2. `dim somestring as string = Ctype(sqlqueryobject, string)`

Neither work, If the sector for `projectID` 1 is named `Zero` - How do I program it to return this value?

Comment: Give us table structures on your sql server, please

Answer (score 0):

The LINQ query you have given will return a list containing the elements that meet the criteria in your Where clause. For the query to only return a single value you need to apply either `.Single()`, `.SingleOrDefault()`, `.First()` or `.FirstOrDefault()` to the query.

For example the following would return either a single scalar value or the default value of the type being returned.

```
Dim sector = (From a In db.Project1 
              Where a.ProjectID = projectID
              Select a.Sector
             ).SingleOrDefault()
```

Further information about these methods can be found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544322/returning-a-single-value-with-linq-to-sql) question.