# LINQ Sum of prices in each month in loop?

Tags: c#, linq

So I'm trying to have a list of profits in each month from my database.
I want to do this in loop, I thnik it will be the best soulution.

Here we have a loop, that I want to count a profit for each month.

```
        using (var context = new ModelContext("ConnectionStringDbMagazynier"))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
            {

                decimal q = (from ar in context.Archives
                             where ar.SalesDate <= DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).AddMonths(i + 1) && ar.SalesDate >= DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).AddMonths(i)
                             let sum = context.Archiwum.Sum(x => x.Price)
                             select sum);

                profits[i] = decimal.ToDouble(q);

            }
        }
```

from this query i get an error:

```
Error   2   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<decimal>' to 'decimal'
```

My question is, how to make it witohut error? and is this solution ok? What in case, that i didn't sell anything in partiuclar month and the sum is null?

Comment: with .Any() i get "Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'decimal'"

Comment: Sorry.  Try `.Single()`  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544322/returning-a-single-value-with-linq-to-sql

Comment: Better still, .SingleOrDefault() so the result will be 0 if there are no sales that month.

Comment: Hi, thanks, for help, i know it would be easier, the case is i have to do this in LINQ, that's the asigment

Comment: You're querying from two tables, but I don't see any coorelation defined between them.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to use lambda syntax in this case.

```
var q = context.Archives
    .Where(ar => ar.SalesDate <= DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).AddMonths(i + 1) && ar.SalesDate >= DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).AddMonths(i))
    .Sum(x => x.Price);
```

Or if you really like the query syntax

```
var records = (from ar in context.Archives
    where ar.SalesDate <= DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).AddMonths(i + 1) && ar.SalesDate >= DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).AddMonths(i)
    select ar);

profits[i] = records.Sum(x => x.Price);
```

Comment: i get this "The cast to value type 'System.Decimal' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type."

Comment: Can the `Price` field be null?  If it can, use `x => x.Price.GetValueOrDefault()`.

Comment: it can't be, but what if i didn't sell anything that month? so mu sum get's nothing, right?

Comment: In theory, Sum should give you zero if you don't have any records, but sometimes Linq to Sql fails to achieve this.  Either put a `ToList()` at the end of your where clause (on the line before `.Sum(x => x.Price)` for the lambda syntax and at the end of the definition of `records` in the query syntax), or use `Sum(x => x.Price) ?? 0`.

Comment: x => x.Price.GetValueOrDefault() I cant do sth like this, only GetType, CompareTo, Equals...

Comment: You won't if `Price` can't be null.

Answer (score 0):

```
var q = context.Archives
.Where(p => p.SalesDate <= DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).AddMonths(i + 1) && p.SalesDate >= DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).AddMonths(i))
.Sum(x => x.Price.HasValue ? x.Price.Value : 0);
```

It's possible get month stat without loop

```
  var grouped = context.Archives.Where(p=> p.SalesDate <= DateTime.Now.AddYear(-1))
.GroupBy(k => new {Year = k.Year, Month = k.Month})
.Select(p=> {Date = p.Key, Sum = p.Sum(x=> x.Price.HasValue ? x.Price.Value : 0)})
```