# LINQ: Returning an empty string/null instead of an System.InvalidOperationException error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have this linq query:

```
string appuserid = (from c in db.AppUsers
                          where (c.AppUserID == AppUserId)
                          select c.AppUserID).Single().ToString();
```

Lets say testuser1 does not exist in the db

If I let `AppUserId = testuser1` I get:

> System.InvalidOperationException.

My question is, is there anyway to rewrite this query to avoid this error and perhaps return an empty string or let it be null? I need to return something that I can write some logic around.

Comment: Use `SingleOrDefault` it will return a null if it doesnt exist.

Comment: @paqogomez you mean FirstOrDefault I guess.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Returning a single value with Linq to SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544322/returning-a-single-value-with-linq-to-sql)

Comment: @DimitarTsonev, both exist and are used for different reasons.

Comment: In that same link it explains `DefaultIfEmpty` as well which may be of use in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the method `SingleOrDefault`. Then you could check if that you get is not or not.

```
var appUser = (from c in db.AppUsers
                 where c.AppUserID == AppUserId
                 select c).SingleOrDefault();

if(appUser!=null)
    var appUserId = appUser.AppUserID.ToString();
```

Or more compact:

```
var appUser = db.AppUsers.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.AppUserID==AppUserId);

if(appUser!=null)
    var appUserId = appUser.AppUserID.ToString();
```

The method `SingleOrDefault` returns the single item from a sequence for which the predicate (the expression in the where clause) is true. If there are more than one items, for which the predicate is true, an exception will be thrown. Furthermore, if there isn't any item in the sequence for which the predicate is true, you will get the default value for the projected item.

Answer (score 2):

```
string appuserid = (from c in db.AppUsers
                          where (c.AppUserID == AppUserId)
                          select c.AppUserID).SingleOrDefault() ?? String.Empty;
```

This will return an empty string.

Comment: Since the default of a string is null, this will throw a `NullReferenceException`

Comment: You are correct.  I fixed it to return an empty string if null;

Comment: operator _??_ can't be applied for operans from _AppUsers_ and _string_

Comment: We are selecting AppUserID which I'm assuming is a String.  We can use ?? on a String.

Comment: @kirkmcpherson, Actually his code ends with `.ToString()` - so I doubt `AppUserID` itself is a `string`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
string appuserid = (from c in db.AppUsers
                          where (c.AppUserID == AppUserId)
                          select c.AppUserID).SingleOrDefault();
```

This will return null, if no element found.